# Prove $\lim_{(x,y)\to (1,b)}\frac{(x-1)^2}{yg(x)}$ exists where $b\neq0$, $g'(x)>1$?

Tags: limits

$\displaystyle \lim_{(x,y)\to (1,b)}\frac{(x-1)^2}{yg(x)}$ where $b\neq0$, $g'(x)>1$ for all $x\in\mathbb R$, $g(1)=0$.

The $y$ at the denominator is pretty annoying, which prevent my using L'Hopital.

Comment: Since $b \neq 0$, you should be able to separate $1/y$ from the rest of the expression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $\displaystyle \lim_{(x,y)\to (1,b)}\frac{(x-1)^2}{yg(x)}=\displaystyle \left(\lim_{(x,y)\to (1,b)}\frac{(x-1)^2}{g(x)}\right)\left(\displaystyle \lim_{(x,y)\to (1,b)}\frac{1}{y}\right)$.  Can you take it from there?